# mv confusion: I deleted /usr/local/bin by following the socketxp guide, but only the first time around

Tags: linux, bin, mv

I was following the [SocketXP Agent Download & Setup](https://www.socketxp.com/download), and on the very first step I am asked to run the following command:

> curl -O https://portal.socketxp.com/download/linux/socketxp && chmod +wx socketxp && sudo mv socketxp /usr/local/bin

This was followed by some confusion, becuase the `bin`-folder now appeared to be an executable. It turns out that rather than inserting `socketxp` into the `/usr/local/bin` folder, I actually deleted the whole folder and replaced it with the `socketxp` file, now renamed to a file called `bin`.

However, after recreating the folder, I see I can transfer test files into it without issues with

> ~touch test
>
> ~sudo mv test /usr/local/bin

So after seeing this, I re-ran the same `socketxp` installation command, and this time around it worked fine.

I'm at a loss as to what the original problem was, but I am very interested in not having this happen again. I suspect I am missing some basic `mv` knowledge. Grateful for any tips and pointers that can explain for me what caused the issue

I was doing this on a 64-bit Linux SIMATIC controller from Siemens, which runs an OS based on Debian.

Comment: The installation script apparently expected `/usr/local/bin` to exist and be a directory, which is indeed a common and reasonable expectation. If you are on a platform which doesn't create this directory by default, maybe submit a bug report to them. (Probably they'll just tell you that you are expected to know what you are doing when mucking with their system, though.)

Comment: Perhaps more fruitful then to submit a bug report to SocketXP, who might reasonably make their installation script cope with this anomaly, even if it is probably a very marginal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am asked to run the following command:
>
> > curl -O https://portal.socketxp.com/download/linux/socketxp && chmod +wx socketxp && sudo mv socketxp /usr/local/bin
>
> This was followed by some confusion, becuase the `bin`-folder now
> appeared to be an executable. It turns out that rather than inserting
> `socketxp` into the `/usr/local/bin` folder, I actually deleted the whole
> folder and replaced it with the `socketxp` file, now renamed to a file
> called `bin`.

Not plausible.  When the destination path in a `mv` command is a directory, the source file(s) are moved into that directory (unless that is overridden by a command-line option).  This is consistent with what you observed in subsequent experiments.

However, if only one source is given and the destination path either does not exist (but its parent directory does) or designates a regular file, then `mv` renames the source to the destination.  We can only guess about what actually happened, but my first guess would be that `/usr/local/bin` did not initially exist.  That might have arisen because of an earlier error, such as executing `rm -rf /usr/local/bin` when you really meant `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/*`, or perhaps the machine just came that way.

Comment: This was indeed the issue, the directory never existed originally. I was able to re-create the original issue by deleting the directory and running the same command. Thank you very much for spotting that.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can use `mv` also to rename files. To prevent a mistake like yours, always add a / at the end of a path that you want to move something into:

`sudo mv test /usr/local/bin/`

This would have behaved as you expected and put the file *test* into the folder */usr/local/bin*.

As @JohnBollinger stated, the behaviour to expect would be that `mv` moves files into an existing folder if you do not explicitly tell it that the last parameter is NOT a directory.

In your case it could have been that */usr/local/bin* simply didn't exist when you executed your command. In this case the variant with the appended / would have emitted an error message. Or you accidentally specified the option -T (maybe intended for some other command or a copy-paste-mistake?)

Comment: There is no reason for the `mv` command presented by the OP to have behaved as they claim it did. In particular, although appending `/` to the destination path does tell `mv` that you expect it to be a directory, omitting that *does not* imply that `mv` should treat it as an ordinary file.

Comment: Thanks for that hint @JohnBollinger, learned something new ;)